# Disable BLE Connection Parameters Negotiation (Linux/Raspberry)

Tags: linux, bluetooth-lowenergy, raspberry-pi4, bluez

Is it possible to configure a Raspberry (or a Linux Machine) to do not negotiate the BLE connection parameters during a connection in which the Raspberry has "Central role" and another device has the "peripheral role"?

Comment: As far as I know, negotiating the connection parameters is mandatory. The only thing you can do is limit the acceptable range by editing the bluetooth service .conf file

Comment: I changed the connection interval of Raspberry through the hci kernel filesystem interface:
    > `echo  6 > /sys/kernel/debug/bluetooth/hci0/conn_min_interval`
    > `echo  10 > /sys/kernel/debug/bluetooth/hci0/conn_max_interval`

Initially the peripheral device accepts this interval but after some seconds it proposes its interval. The Raspberry (central role) accepts this new interval.

I know that the Central can refuse the new interval and in this case the peripheral can close the connection.

How can configure my Raspberry to do not accept the new intervals ?

Comment: Hmm, if that is what happens then I dont know how to fix it...sorry. Try raising an issue on the Bluez repo on github